# Limit KineticJS Drag to one direction only

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to build a real simple lawn mower intro page. There are two images, one that serves as a background, and the other as the handle that you drag across.

Is there a way to set it up so that the dragging event only happens in one direction, left-to-right in particular?

[What I have so far.](http://yaktailsdemo.com/mower/test-3/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to lawnMowerImg that acts as a left boundary to dragging:

```
    lawnMowerImg.minX=lawnMowerImg.getX();
```

Then, in dragBoundFunc, if the drag attempts to move left of minX, then set the pos.x = min.X:

```
    if(pos.x<this.minX){  pos.x=this.minX; }
    this.minX=pos.x;
```

So the modified lawnMowerImg would look like this:

And here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hfE6A/

```
    var lawnMowerImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 896 / 1,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 255 / 2,
      width: 896,
      height: 255,
      draggable: true,
      dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
          if(pos.x<this.minX){  pos.x=this.minX; }
          this.minX=pos.x;
          return {
            x: pos.x,
            y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
          }
      }
    });
    lawnMowerImg.minX=lawnMowerImg.getX();
```

Comment: I also wanted to limit how much distance to the right the user can drag the image, so I added `if (pos.x > maxX) { pos.x = maxX; }` to my `dragBoundFunc` and `maxX = stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() - lawnMowerImg.getWidth() + 250;` The demo's still up if you want to see [link]http://yaktailsdemo.com/mower/test-3/intro.html